# jquery cycle: overriding the width?

Tags: jquery, cycle, jquery-cycle

I'm using jQuery Cycle, but it's automatically setting the width of the div on its own.

The div that is cycled has ID #slideshow, so I am currently having to modify the CSS

```
#slideshow {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this using the jQuery Cycle options rather than having to use !important.

Any tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: I've never used that plugin, but a quick search landed me on the [jQuery Cycle Plugin Options](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html) page, which has things such as width and fit. What options are you using with the plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[set width option as](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html)

```
width: "100%"  // container width (if the 'fit' option is true, the slides will be set to this width as well)
```

Comment: i think you forgot to put in "" as width: "100%"